# std::ifstream sets the eofbit at the point when the last item in the file is read, but it only happens when reading numerical types

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

Suppose given a non-empty text file containing a list of numbers,

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

and we read them with `std::ifstream` into numerical types (`int`, `double`, etc.) as well as `char`

```
int main()
{
    ifstream fs {"textfile.txt"};
    int val {0}; //read into ints
    for (int i{0}; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        //read five times
        fs >> val;
        cout << val << " is read. Current state of file stream: "
            << bitset<3> (fs.rdstate()) << endl; //check stream state after each read                        
    }
}
```

When read as numerical types, the program outputs:

```
1 is read. Current state of fs: 000
2 is read. Current state of fs: 000
3 is read. Current state of fs: 000
4 is read. Current state of fs: 000
5 is read. Current state of fs: 010
```

At the point when the last item of the file is read, the eofbit was set.

But the same thing doesn't happen when reading into `char`s.

```
int main()
{
    ifstream fs {"textfile.txt"};
    char ch {0}; //read into chars
    for (int i{0}; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        //read five times
        fs >> ch;
        cout << ch << " is read. Current state of file stream: "
            << bitset<3> (fs.rdstate()) << endl; //check stream state after each read                        
    }
}
```

which outputs:

```
1 is read. Current state of fs: 000
2 is read. Current state of fs: 000
3 is read. Current state of fs: 000
4 is read. Current state of fs: 000
5 is read. Current state of fs: 000
```

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 2):

You get `EOF` when reading `int`s because the stream extraction operator for `int` tries to read till it finds either a whitespace or something unsuitable for an `int`. So it will try to read another `char` after the `5` was read, encounters the end of the file and the `eofbit` gets set.

In contrast, the stream extraction operator for `char` will only ever try to read one `char` so it won't encounter the end of the file. Try and read 6 `char`s from the file and you will also encounter `EOF`.